# angular-translate: Translate a string to a specific language in the controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using angular-translate and would like to report a certain text to analytics

So I know I can use this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl', ['$translate', ,'$analytics', '$scope', function ($translate, $analytics, $scope) {

  $analytics.reportEvent(EVENT_NAME, {headline: $translate('HEADLINE_TEXT')});

}]);
```

BUT: this translates to the language currently in use.

**I need the ENGLISH translation of this text regardless of the user's display language.**

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the language by using `$translation.use('en')` ([docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate)).

```
$translate.use('en').then(function () {
    $translate('HEADLINE_TEXT');
});
```

However, if you always want it to be in english, there's no much point to use a translation service, just hardcode the english message.

**EDIT:**

The docs are unclear whether it will change the language for the rest of the app. If so, you'll probably need to keep a reference to the old language and restore it after, something like (**untested**):

```
var currentLanguage = $translate.use();
$translate.use('en').then(...);
$translate.use(currentLanguage);
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't this change the language for the entire app?